# How to remove outliers in a text dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a program that reads a text file and sorts the data into name, job, company and location fields in the form of a pandas dataframe. The location field is the same for all of the rows except for one or two outliers. I want to remove these rows from the df and put them in a separate list.
Example:

```
    Name   Job   Company   Location
 1.  n1     j1      c1        l
 2.  n2     j2      c2        l
 3.  n3     j3      c3        x
 4.  n4     j4      c4        l
```

Is there a way to remove only the row with location 'x'(row 3)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Armadillo, if you would like to be helped you need to provide some code, some inputs and desidered output, otherwise is hard to help

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the two groups into separate DFS

```
same_df = df.query('location == "<onethatisthesame>"')
```

Then I would repeat this but using != To get the others

```
other_df = df.query('location =! "<onethatisthesame>"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
import pandas as pd

# df = df[df['location'] == yourRepeatedValue]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['location'] )
df.at[1, 'location'] = 'mars'
df.at[2, 'location'] = 'pluto'
df.at[3, 'location'] = 'mars'
print(df)
df = df[df['location'] == 'mars']
print(df)
```

This will create a new DataFrame that only contains `yourRepeatedValue`.

In the example, the new `df` won't contain rows that are different from `'mars'`

The output would be:

```
  location
1     mars
2    pluto
3     mars
  location
1     mars
3     mars
```